# How to copy to clipboard exact git message to use in another commit

Tags: git, git-commit

I have to create a commit with the same message as another. First thing I thought was simple to run

```
git show 7777777777
```

and copy the message from the console, but the message is complicated, has multi lines and spaces/tabs.

So I am afraid that in the copy + paste process I would miss anything.

Is there a command to copy to clipboard the git message of a given commit?

Comment: "The clipboard" is OS-specific. On macOS use `pbcopy`, e.g., `git log --no-walk --format=%B <commit> | pbcopy`. The `-C` method is generally superior though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git commit` has a [`-C | --reuse-message`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--Cltcommitgt) option :

```
git commit -C 7777777777
```

note that it also copies the author and the creation date from that original commit.

---

You can also use `git log -1 --format="%B" 7777777777`  (or `git show -s --format="%B" 7777777777` ) to get just the commit message from your original commit, and combine it with [`git commit -F`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--Fltfilegt) :

```
git log -1 --format="%B" 7777777777 > /tmp/message
git commit -F /tmp/message

# to read the commit message from stdin :
git log -1 --format="%B" 7777777777 | git commit -F -
```