# Git copy commit without checkout or rebase?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, rebase

I am currently on commit 123456 and branch `foo`. I'd like to add a new commit to branch `bar` with the exact contents of 123456 (not rebased, just created from the same snapshot, so the diff will be whatever it will be).

I can accomplish this like so:

```bash
$ git checkout bar
$ git reset foo
$ git commit -am '...'
$ git checkout foo
```

I have two questions:

- Is there a way of doing this without needing to leave `foo` or needing to change my working tree?
- Is there a clean way that I can copy the commit message from 123456? (I can obviously do it manually, but automatically via native git commands would be nice)

Comment: Hi. A branch is a pointer, and nothing more. In the exact situation you described, you simply need to use `git branch bar`.

Comment: "*Is there a way of doing this without needing to leave foo or needing to change my working tree?*" I don't know any. Git can only add commits on top of the currently checked out commit (not necessary a branch) so to add commits to branch `bar` you must check it out. It's not necessary to do in the current working tree — if your repository doesn't use submdodules you can use [`git worktree add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) to create a different worktree with the branch `bar` checked out there and create a new commit in the separate worktree.

Comment: @phd look at my answer, I am sure you will find it _insightful_.

Comment: "*Is there a clean way that I can copy the commit message from 123456?*" https://stackoverflow.com/a/67726645/7976758 `git commit -C 123456 --reset-author` or  `git commit -c 123456 --reset-author` (the latter opens an editor to edit the message).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to do

```
git checkout bar
git restore --worktree --staged --source=foo -- .
git commit -m "Here we make it just like 1234546 (or foo back when I created this commit)"
```

You can use `git commit -C 123456` to use that commit's information for the new commit *but* it would be misleading because you are creating a single commit *and* you are disregarding all history in `foo..bar`.... does it make sense to do that in a single commit? Well, perhaps it does for your use case *but* I wouldn't assume it will work for everybody.

And sure, it can be done without changing your working tree.... by using a superduper **second** working tree. So, check `git help worktree`.

Now that I think about it, there is yet another way to do it without having to move a single bit from your working tree and without needing a second working tree, but it's hackish:

```
# we are on foo, right?
git branch temp $( git commit-tree -p bar -m "Here we make it just like 1234546 (or foo back when I created this commit)" 123456^{tree}" )
# commit-tree is a command not intended for the faint-of-heart. It
# will create a new commit just like 123456 in contents and that has bar
# as its parent.... and the outer command will set the branch temp
# on it.
# It's a hackish thing so no -C available to copy the info from
# 123456.
# if you like it, then move bar to that position
git branch -f bar temp
# and now you can delete temp
git branch -D temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're after the core commands, the ones the usual conveniences are built on. The core make-a-commit command is `git commit-tree`, it wants parents, tree, message. The core set-a-ref command is `git update-ref`, you want bar pointing at a new commit parented on its current tip, so

```
git update-ref refs/heads/bar $(
        git show -s --pretty=format:%B @ \
        | git commit-tree -p bar @: 
)
```